# Orchard and the Dashboard UI, "friendlyfy"?

Tags: user-interface, admin, umbraco, orchardcms, dashboard

I just started to investigate Orchard for the 5:th time, and I thought that I might want to give it a fair chance.. however.. there is one think that me and my collegues simply cant get our heads around.. why is the UI so "techy"?.. For instance Umbraco has a very clean and simple Admin UI thats mostly understandable by anyone (even "none tech" persons)..
So my question is basically, is there something that we are missing?.. is there any user advantage to the Orchard Dashboard UI over the Umbraco UI for instance, or is there any module thats a "must have" to  make the UI a bit more familiar?

Answer (score 2):

Every time i have a new orchard instance, i always install the module Theme Editor
https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.M33.SystemEditor

This module allows you to edit Views, JS, CSS inside of the cms itself. This probably complicates the UI even more however.

To answer your question, there is nothing to my knowledge to make the UI easier to adapt to. However if you spend the time to get to learn it then you realize there are a lot of very powerful things you can do with it and it is a fantastic example of MVC that is at your fingertips to modify to your hearts content.

Comment: Do visit the chat some time soon.  It appears you are in San Diego, CA, USA.  Thought you planned to graduate.